# DSpace input-field visibility

Tags: submit, workflow, visibility, dspace

With the DSpace visibility tag on some fields in input-forms.xml I try to hide these input fields during the submit, while these fields have to be visible during the workflow process (workflow)
These input fields are indeed invisible when I submit a document. But unfortunately they stay invisible when I open the same document (edit) again as user with workflow rights to perform the next step: adding extra information and approving the document for the repository.

I tried above with two different repositories, one with DSpace 5.2 and one with DSpace 5.4. Both with the same results.

In DSpace 5.2 I also tried the opposite: I tagged an item with submit: the field is now visible in the submit step, but also in the workflow step.

In the DSpace manual I cannot find what I could possibly do wrong. Do I misunderstand the workflow process? Or is there an extra configuration step that has to be taken?

Comment: Can you give us the relevant part of your `input-forms.xml` file please (all the variants you tried)?

Comment: <field>
         <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
         <dc-element>description</dc-element>
         <dc-qualifier></dc-qualifier>
         <repeatable>false</repeatable>
         <label>Description</label>
         <input-type>textarea</input-type>
         <hint>Enter any other description or comments in this box. </hint>
         <required></required>
         <visibility>workflow</visibility>
</field>
(sorry, I don't know how to format this code)

Comment: It's probably "best practice" for Stack Overflow for you to edit your question and add the code there, rather than adding it as a comment. That way you can use the editor buttons too for getting the code formatting to show up.

Comment: And one final comment -- I'm a little confused by your description of "when I open the same document (edit) again as user with workflow rights". Just to be super clear, this is the process you're following, yes? (1) Submitter creates new submission, fills in fields / uploads file, grants licence. (2) The submission shows up in "tasks in the pool". (3) Reviewer takes the task and clicks "Edit metadata".

Comment: I added a comment earlier to say this may be different between JSPUI and XMLUI (you don't say what you're using; I used XMLUI in my testing). However, it looks like the code that controls this behaviour is identical between the two UIs.

Comment: Sorry Sweerelos, the last days I had no time to work on it. Same for the next days.
More and more I suppose I did something wrong when configuring the workflow. BTW My testings I did mostly with JSPUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [DSpace 5.x Submission interface docs](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-CustomMetadata-entryPagesforSubmission), it looks like you should be able to do this to have the field appear *only* during submission:

```
   <field>
     <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
     <dc-element>title</dc-element>
     <dc-qualifier>alternative</dc-qualifier>
     <repeatable>true</repeatable>
     <label>Other Titles</label>
     <input-type>onebox</input-type>
     <hint>If the item has any alternative titles, please enter them here.</hint>
     <required></required>
     <visibility>submit</visibility>
   </field>
```

or *only* during the review workflow:

```
   <field>
     <dc-schema>dc</dc-schema>
     <dc-element>title</dc-element>
     <dc-qualifier>alternative</dc-qualifier>
     <repeatable>true</repeatable>
     <label>Other Titles</label>
     <input-type>onebox</input-type>
     <hint>If the item has any alternative titles, please enter them here.</hint>
     <required></required>
     <visibility>workflow</visibility>
   </field>
```

If you omit the "visibility" element, it will appear in both the submission form and the review workflow.

Which of these did you try? And what behaviour did you get, if it wasn't the expected behaviour?

Comment: Sweerelos, I tried both.

With <visibility>submit</visibility> the field is always visible (as well in submit as in workflow mode).

With <visibility>workflow</visibility> the field is never visible.

Comment: Are you sure you're making the change for the right submission form / your change is actually applied? I just tried this on a 5.1 instance and the behaviour I'm describing above works just fine. The only thing I couldn't get to work is the behaviour of the "otherwise" attribute -- `<visibility otherwise="readonly">submit</visibility>` only shows up during submission (I haven't tried `<visibility otherwise="readonly">workflow</visibility>`).

Comment: Yes, it must  be the right form, because in the submit phase the behavior is alright: the field is not visible with <visibility>workflow</visibility>. 
Only in the workflow phase DSpace seems to react as if I am in the sumit phase.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a misunderstanding from my side.
As Administrator I could archive an earlier submitted item/document, so I thought: now I am in the workflow process. But if the Administrator is not part of a moderator-group DSpace sees this process still as a submit and not as a workflow. By that, the visibility of metadata fields is still that for a submitter.
After adding my account to a moderator-group I could see the 'Tasks in Pool' and I could take one of more of the tasks. And when editting one of the items I could see and use the 'workflow'-metatdata-fields.